# Intel Compiler 17 on Amd Ryzen

Tags: visual-studio, intel, amd-processor

My dev environment is Visual Studio 2015 and Intel Compiler 17. I just switched on a new machine with an AMD Ryzen processor.

On my old Intel 3930K everything worked, but now, on this new machine, the Intel Compiler R17, even if is installed, is not present in the properties of my projects.

Properties of a project:

[image]

Does anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 2):

Try to reinstall the Intel compiler and check the visual studio option.
Please be aware that the Intel compiler deliberately produces code that runs suboptimally on AMD processors.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should think about switching compilers if you do not use any low-level Intel compiler features.

Try http://developer.amd.com/x86-open64-compiler-suite/ instead?

Also take note of Intel's compiler notice https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/optimization-notice#opt-en

Comment: Note that the Open64 Compiler suite is (sadly...) discontinued, with last major version released 5 years ago (V4.5.2 on 8/8/12).

Comment: Thanks for this information. What is AMD's alternative?

Comment: AOCC:  
http://developer.amd.com/amd-aocc.
Just got aquainted with it myself! Said to be LLVM 4.0 based (nice move AMD).  
According to Phoronix, Ryzen benchmarks are pretty at par with clang 4.0: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=amd-ryzen-aocc&num=1